# Receive notifications for specific tags

Tags: feature-request, tags, notifications

Is there any way to receive a notification (email and SO inbox would both be good) if a question with a particular tag shows up?

I'd like to know if a question about `D`, `C#` (or even `Eeeeeeeeeeeeeeek`!) shows up. :D

If not, might I suggest that this be implemented sometime in the future? :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Email is easy, if you hover your mouse over the tag [feature-request] on the right side, carefully slide the mouse down then over to `subscribe` and find your inbox filled with mails about new questions with the tag.

No idea about SO Inbox, I *think* I'd like it, or some on-screen notification of new ones since the last I looked...

Comment: I did *not* know about the subscribe link, that's awesome! :D +1